# Why do I have to IF return, IF what?

Tags: javascript

I am learning to code or rather - even reading the code at this moment.
Could anyone please explain me, why those lines are there and what do they do?

```
  if (noClicking) return;
  if (e.target.classList.contains("flipped")) return;
```

What is the purpose of those two lines?

```
    function handleCardClick(e) {
  // you can use event.target to see which element was clicked

  if (noClicking) return;
  if (e.target.classList.contains("flipped")) return;

  let currentCard = e.target;
  currentCard.style.backgroundColor = currentCard.classList[0];

  if (!card1 || !card2) {
    currentCard.classList.add("flipped");
    card1 = card1 || currentCard;
    card2 = currentCard === card1 ? null : currentCard;
  }

  if (card1 && card2) {
    noClicking = true;
    // debugger
    let gif1 = card1.className;
    let gif2 = card2.className;

    if (gif1 === gif2) {
      cardsFlipped += 2;
      card1.removeEventListener("click", handleCardClick);
      card2.removeEventListener("click", handleCardClick);
      card1 = null;
      card2 = null;
      noClicking = false;
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        card1.style.backgroundColor = "";
        card2.style.backgroundColor = "";
        card1.classList.remove("flipped");
        card2.classList.remove("flipped");
        card1 = null;
        card2 = null;
        noClicking = false;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  if (cardsFlipped === COLORS.length) alert("game over!");
}
```

Comment: If the `noClicking` flag is set, or if the class list of the target of the event that triggered this call contained the class "flipped", then you'll exit the function immediately without doing anything else.

Comment: Ohhh, so that checks IF true. Thank you so much! I was losing my mind over this

Answer (score 0):

```
if (noClicking) return;
if (e.target.classList.contains("flipped")) return;
```

The lines below those 2 lines will not be executed if one of the 2 lines are returned.
It means if `noClicking == true` or `e.target.classList.contains("flipped") == true`, then all the lines below those 2 lines will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

While the answers already given are correct, I thought it could help to understand **why** those lines are there in place. They are called guard clauses. Their purpose is to make your code more efficient.

Think of a scenario like this:

```js
function myFunc(someParam) {
  /*
  do something that takes a lot of time/resources

  ... then somewhere you find someParam was invalid!
  so all the calculations done until now was useless
  */
}
```

So instead of checking the validity of arguments, global variables, etc. when you need them in the function, you check for them in the beginning of the function such as like this:

```js
function myFunc(someParam) {
  //let's say valid() is a function that checks for validity of the param,
  //returns true if valid, false if invalid.
  if(!valid(someParam)) return;
  /*
  do something that takes a lot of time/resources

  ... then your function will only run the expensive code
  if it is sure that there are no invalid arguments passed to it.
  */
}
```

It doesn't always have to be just `return`. This is your choice. Maybe the function always returns some positive number, then you could `return -1` as such:

```js
const getRoot = (num) => {
  if(num < 0) return -1;
  //get square root of the number
  return abs(Math.sqrt(num));
}

//Then when you call the function, you could check if the result is not -1,
//to make sure you passed the correct arguments.

if (getRoot(-1) < 0) 
  console.error("Uh oh, you passed a negative number to the square root function");
```

Or you could throw an `Error`:

```js
function myFunc (someParam) {
  if(!valid(someParam)) throw new Error("wrong param bruh");

  //do something...
}
```